# Iterator (string::iterator) behaving as if out of scope?

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I have PDF papers copied/pasted into TXT as input and I want to build a tree of "Section". Each section contains a heading (ex "3.3 Evaluation of the methods") and a text (everything else until the next heading). Both are implemented with iterator_range (which I typedeffed string_range).

I started by having a function elsewhere that returns me the heading number + the very first word after it (it would return "3.3 Evaluation" in the example before and put everything else under text). This function expands the heading.

All that it does is to take the first full stop in the section text, and extend the heading until before the last capitalized word in the text, also shrinking the text accordingly.

The while loop is there to make me reach the last one. If debugged, it works perfectly while INSIDE the loop. Once I leave it, the iterators are screwed. I can't see why.

You may try and run the code yourselves as I have stripped off every other dependance off it - it works the same and runs.

The string temp must be the cause as it's the only thing inside the scope of the while loop - but it doesn't make any sense as I am copying it into the other variable, which is the only thing seen by iterators. The other variable does not go out of scope, so why do the iterators change? I can't think of an explanation :-(

It's not a boost thing because the std::string::iterator unexplainable is doing the same - the class iterator_range has nothing to do with this behaviour...

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string_regex.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

typedef iterator_range<string::iterator> string_range;

int main() {
    string original_text("Mixed Initiative Dialogue Management 2.1 Motivation In naturally occurring human-human dialogues, speakers often adopt different dialogue strategies based on hearer characteristics, dialogue history, etc.For instance, the speaker may provide more guidance if the hearer is hav- ing difficulty making progress toward task completion, while taking a more passive approach when the hearer is an expert in the domain.Our main goal is to enable a spoken dialogue system to simulate such human be- havior by dynamically adapting dialogue strategies dur- ing an interaction based on information that can be au- tomatically detected from the dialogue. Figure 1 shows an excerpt from a dialogue between MIMIC and an ac- tual user where the user is attempting to find the times at which the movie Analyze This playing at theaters in Montclair. S and U indicate system and user utterances, respectively, and the italicized utterances are the output of our automatic speech recognizer.In addition, each system turn is annotated with its task and dialogue ini- tiative holders, where task initiative tracks the lead in the process toward achieving the dialogue participants' do- main goal, while dialogue initiative models the lead in determining the current discourse focus (Chu-Carroll and Brown, 1998). In our information query application do- main, the system has task (and thus dialogue) initiative if its utterances provide helpful guidance toward achieving the user's domain goal, as in utterances (6) and (7) where MIMIC provided valid response choices to its query in- tending to solicit a theater name, while the system has 97 dialogue but not task initiative if its utterances only spec- ify the current discourse goal, as in utterance (4). This dialogue illustrates several features of our adap- tive mixed initiative dialogue manager for dynamic");
    string_range text(original_text.begin(), original_text.end() );
    string first_sentence("Mixed Initiative Dialogue Management 2.1 Motivation In naturally occurring human-human dialogues, speakers often adopt different dialogue strategies based on hearer characteristics, dialogue history, etc.");
    regex capex("((^| )([A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+) )"); // Capitalized word (or fullcapsed word)
    string_range capitalized_word;

    string::iterator unexplainable;
    int count = 0;
    while (find_regex(first_sentence, capex) ) { // Getting the last one
        capitalized_word = find_regex(first_sentence, capex);
        string temp(capitalized_word.end(), first_sentence.end() );
        first_sentence = temp;
        unexplainable = capitalized_word.begin(); // Here is fine
        count++;
    }
    if (count <= 1) return 0;
    string_range new_text_range(unexplainable, text.end()); // Here it gets full of junk... why??
    string new_string(new_text_range.begin(), new_text_range.end() );
    string_range new_text_range2(capitalized_word.begin(), text.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you mix iterators from different sequences and try to create a new sequence from them. The `unexplainable` iterator points to somewhere in the `first_sentence` string while the `text.end()` points to the end of the `original_text` string.

Here's what the memory might look like

```
      0123456789012345
      ----------------
   00 Hello World!0%&(
   16 %£$!*Bye world!0
```

Now say that `unexplainable` points to `6`, i.e "World!" and `text.end()` points to `31`, now if you create a range (and then a string from that range) you will get garbage because the string you'll get will look like this: `"World!0%&(%£$!*Bye world!"`. This is just a made up example but I hope you get the idea: **Don't mix iterators from different sequences!!**

I'll throw in another hint for free: Don't compute `find_regex()` twice, change the loop to something like:

```
do
{
  capitalized_word = find_regex(first_sentence, capex);
  if(capitalized_word)
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}while(capitalized_word);
```

Comment: I computed it twice because I thought that by doing a while (capitalized_word = find_regex(first_sentence, capex) ) I could get a bool into capitalized word, thus screwing everything up.

BTW capitalized word and unexplainable point to junk right after the while. If I put into a debugger and stop before the "if", then it's already full of junk (it is perfectly fine before it). I will try std::distance, but I can't figure out why... Scopes seem fine!

Comment: @Davide: Nope, I think you misunderstood me, the real problem is *not* computing `find_regex()` twice, it's that you *cannot* create a range using iterators from two separate strings.